# SOAP on Subdomains

Tags: php, soap

I am working with an application that is used by multiple clients.  Each client has its own database, but multiple clients use the same php codebase.  In essence, we use named virtual servers on apache to point the url to the right codebase on the server.  When the browser hits the php code, the code checks a master database to see which customer database the url is paired with.

We are adding in a SOAP module to the mix and I am confused how to handle the wsdl file for our soap service.  Essentially, I have one wsdl file per code base.  I just need to be able to configure the wsdl file to handle all of the various subdomains that we use to point to the same code.  Once we hit our SOAP module, it understands what database to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we ended up doing - we abandoned the need for the WSDL.  From the client side, we simply set the appropriate subdomain as the endpoint.  Because we use Mirth to direct our communications to each subdomain, it works well for us.

I did try to use a dynamic wsdl file, but was never able to get it to work in the limited time I had to spend on the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it, but you can have a dynamic WSDL file, which itself is a PHP script. based on the request parameters (that will indicate which customer is requesting), a specific XML data will be generated and sent to the user.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to look into that.